# nodejs respone time performance

Tags: performance, node.js

I did comparison of response time performance between nodejs and java.

Test Enviroment:
OS: Ubuntu 10.10
Server: OpenFire 3.7 
Two server components to compare written using Nodejs(0.4.8) and Java (whack API)

Test Scenario:
Number of concurrent clients sending number of XMPP messages to server and server component is replying back to randomly chosen clients. Total time of reaching response is being calculated.

Test Result:
The response time of both java and nodejs remains same until the load on server is increased in terms of increasing number of messages per client. It is observed that Nodejs appears to be on slower side when messages per second per client is increased to from 5000 to 10000.

Reason:
I tried to search out what will be the reason of this low performance of Nodejs on high load but couldn't find anything conclusive. What I have found is that as Nodejs is single threaded process and it is performing reading and writing in that same thread so when the load is increased on it, the I/O writing gets slower

Please can you explain what could be reason of it? If you need more information, I will be glad to provide that. I also have test data and generated graphs from that data.

Thanks
Best Regards,
Muhammad Ali

Comment: supply information about your benchmarks. Supply information about your processors. Did you use `cluster`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing data is not bound to a single thread, in fact it's using some libraries which will work asynchronously.

**Only your code is running in a single thread**

Maybe your facing problems with the V8 garbage collection, hard to tell. Or, as Raynos pointed, your code for telling the libraries to write to the sockets (not the really sending) is bound by the single core so that it's to slow asking node to send data to all recipients.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple cpu's then node.js will only take advantage of one of them.

try making your test very parallel and then see which one does better. that's where node.js is supposed to shine.